# I am not getting the reason why post method is not executed

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

```
public class ExtractProduct extends HttpServlet   
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ExtractProduct() {
       super();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("bye");
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("hiiiii");   
    }

}
```

JSP Page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
  <body>
     <form name="displayProduct" method='post' action='ExtractProduct.do' >
        <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
   <display-name>adsfa</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExtractProduct</servlet-name>
    <display-name>ExtractProduct</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>
    controller.ExtractProduct</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExtractProduct</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ExtractProduct.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I have clicked the submit button the url pattern is changed and it redirects it to Extractproduct.do but "hii" is not printed to console.can anyone help me.
I am not getting the reason why post method is not executed.

And then I have tried to create new servlet and when I have tried to run the servelet it is showing me a error :
HTTP status 500
internal server error.
Though my all old servelet program run correctly.

Comment: ""hii" is not printed to console" - why do you expect anything to be printed to console ? how console is related to a webservice ?

Comment: My main intention is not to print "hii" in the console.I just want to make sure that doPost method is executed.

Comment: The instead of trying to print to console, try to redirect to a web-page and see if the redirect takes place. For example: `response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: @user3773682 - I checked that it is executed and is visible in the console. I made a simple html page to "call" the servlet. I don't know why you are not getting the same output. You can also add 3-4 lines of code to get and post to generate an html response for testing.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev: Totally agree with you. I also checked.

Comment: @SiddharthM - he probably needs some coffee.

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
  response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");

 }
noop...not working

Comment: are u using servlet only? and ya one thing is that if u using servlet only why to make action into .do format?

Comment: When I tried to create new servlet and run it I have found an error http status --500  The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.It looks like my first problem and second problem are linked.

Comment: try to change URL in web.xml to <url-pattern>ExtractProduct.do</url-pattern>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i believe that you must set them @Override

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("bye");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("hiiiii");   
}
```

Even do you dont do this the default method from the HttpServlet get used.